# Makeshift off Click event not working properly

Tags: jquery

I have found a offClick event using jQuery, but it's not working the way I intended it to.

When I click left eye I want lefteyedes to appear, and it does. But when I click righteye I want righteyedes to appear and lefteyedes to disappear (opacity = 0)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#face").find("*").click(function(){
        $(this).addClass("opacity description");
          $("#face > *").not(this).removeClass("opacity");
                    });


    $('#lefteye').click(function() {
        $('#lefteyedes').removeClass('opacity');
        });             
    $('#face').click(function() {
    $("#lefteyedes").addClass("opacity");
}); 

    $("#lefteye").click(function(e) {
    $("#lefteyedes").removeClass('opacity');
    e.stopPropagation();
});



    $('#righteye').click(function() {
        $('#righteyedes').removeClass('opacity');
        });             
    $('#face').click(function() {
    $("#righteyedes").addClass("opacity");
}); 

    $("#righteye").click(function(e) {
    $("#righteyedes").removeClass('opacity');
    e.stopPropagation();
});



});


</script>


<style>
.opacity {
    opacity: 0;
    }
#face {
    background-image: url(face.png);
    width: 262px;
    height: 262px;
    }
#lefteye {
    background-image: url(circle.png);
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    position: relative;
    top: 69px;
    left: 59px;
    }
#righteye {
    background-image: url(circle.png);
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    position: relative;
    top: 41px;
    left: 167px;
    }
#mouth {
    background-image: url(circle.png);
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    position: relative;
    top: 84px;
    left: 114px;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <br><br>
    <div id="face">
        <div id="lefteye">
        </div>
        <div id="righteye">
        </div>
        <div id="mouth">
        </div>
    </div>
        <div id="lefteyedes" class="opacity">
            <p>Left Eye</p>
        </div>
        <div id="righteyedes" class="opacity">
            <p>Right Eye</p>
        </div>
        <div id="mouthdes" class="opacity">
            <p>Mouth</p>
        </div>
```

Comment: Could you provide an example with the HTML, or use a fiddle to show us what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly. When you click `#righteye` you want to `righteyedes` to appear, or in other-words remove the class `opacity` to it. So I'm assuming your `opacity` class is to "hide" items. I want to note you can use simply `.hide()` and `.show()` to do this. But going with your code you can do this:

```
$('#righteye').click(function() { // When you click #righteye
    $('#righteyedes').removeClass('opacity'); // Show #righteyedes
    $('#lefteyedes').addClass('opacity'); // Hide #lefteyedes
});
```

Comment: Yes this is correct in a way, but I am using man elements like mouth, ears, hair ect, so would I have to do $('mouth').addClass('opacity'), ears, ect? I feel like there is a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: @ChrisCampos Could you clarify exactly what you are trying to do here, I don't see your program or know what you want to do. Would you want to hide all items except for what you have clicked?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I'm trying to do. I'll try to explain it a little better. So when the page loads all the 'des' elements are invisible (opacity: 0) When I click on a an element like 'left eye' I want 'lefteyedes' to appear, then when I click on 'right eye' I want 'righteyedes' to appear, and 'lefteyedes' to disappear. Then when I click on 'mouth' I want 'mouthdes' to appear and righteyedes to disappear. This will go on for the rest of my element's such as 'ear' 'hair' and 'nose'.